# Is it possible to check injectivity of a homomorphism by checking just the generators of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group with generators $\{g_i\}_{i\in I}$.

Let $\psi:G\to H$ be a group homomorphism (to another group $H$).

Is it possible to check injectivity of $\psi$ just by checking the generators?

That is, if $\psi(g_i)=\psi(g_j)$ implies $g_i=g_j$ for all $i$, $j$, does it necessarily mean that $\psi$ is injective?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Take $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb Z$ define by $\varphi(x,y)=x+2y$. The group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and $\varphi(1,0)\neq\varphi(0,1)$. However, $\varphi$ is *not* injective.

Comment: Nice answer that is technically correct. I wonder if there is an example that satisfies the condition "if $\psi(g_i)=\psi(g_j)$ then $g_i=g_j$" non-trivially though.

Comment: @yoyostein What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what I wrote does not make sense. I understand now. Your example is perfect!

Comment: @yoyostein I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

No. With what you suggest, the map $\Psi: G\to G$ that is the identity on all generators except one, $g_1$ which is mapped to $e$, would be injective.

Or if for instance every $g_i$ is of infinite order you could define $\phi(g_i)=g_1^i$, which is again strongly not injective but fails your test.

Comment: I find your first example even more evident in the degenerate case where $G$ has only one generator, and $f(x)=e$ is then trivially injective on generators, and trivially not injective in general.

Comment: Your examples work best when $G$ is freely generated by the $g_i$, but not well otherwise (i.e., $\Psi$ and $\phi$ may not even define homomorphisms)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen True. That was the idea. Not sure it's worth downvoting though but anyway.